# Time counter using react and moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I would like to create a timer and formatting the view to `mm:ss`

Here's my actual component

```
import moment from 'moment'
const Timer = ({ callQueuedTime }) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(() => new Date().getTime() / 1000 - callQueuedTime);
    useEffect(() => {
        const queuedTime = callQueuedTime;
        const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            setTime(() => new Date().getTime() / 1000 - queuedTime);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            console.log(intervalId)
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, [callQueuedTime]);
    return <div className="timer">{moment(time).format('mm:ss')}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

My actual issue is that using `{moment(time).format('mm:ss')}` is not updating view or values are not well formatte because I'm getting `00:01` using timestamp `1588087827` for `callQueueTime` and `17:53` as `new Date()`

Comment: Do you want to run a decreasing timer, what is the role of callQueuedTime

Comment: callQueueTime is a starting time, I would like to show the time since the `callQueueTime` value

Comment: Check this demo please: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-germain-wgz28?file=/src/App.js

It is based on assumption that you have queue time of some ms.

Comment: is it possible to not change the effect function ? I would like to keep the timer calculation  outside the render function

Comment: yes, that can be done, but does the demo meet your needs. If it does, I will update it

Comment: Yes but with a small diff, your example make a countdown what I would is the opposite add time every second ( time counter )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212714/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-infodev).